How can I get a scoped DataContext into DBLogger in .Net 8 Razor
I got a DBLogger implementing ILogger and also myDBLoggerProvider implementing ILoggerProvider in a Razor Project A. This requires a DataContext of type SysDataContextBase to be able to write logs into a database. SysDataContextBase is also defined in Project A.
In my Main Project, I referenced Project A and in the program.cs I have the following:
builder.Services.AddDbContext<SysDataContextBase>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(IdentityConnectionString));

// Logging ----------------------------------------------------------
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddDBLogger();
builder.Logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.*", LogLevel.None);

In my Main Project, I have also a class named SysDataContext that inherits SysDataContextBase. How can I scoop the SysDataContext from my Main Project into my DBLogger, please?
JP
